# Linear Transformations from Matrices to Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

Let $T: M_{2x2} \rightarrow P_3$ be the linear transformation

$$T( \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\ 
c & d
\end{bmatrix})=(a+c)x^3+(a+b+c)x^2+(d-a-c)x+(a+b+c+d)$$

a) Find bases for the kernel and range of $T$ and compute their dimensions. For the kernel, do I make all of the coeffients=0? Like $(a+c)=0, (a+b+c)=0$... and solve? If so, I just get that $a=-c, b=0,$ $c:$ free,$d=0,$ so would the basis for kernel be the matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
with dimension 1? For the range, I reduced the same matrix that I did for the kernel, found the pivot columns (columns 1,2, and 4) and wrote the basis as the set of those original columns: {(x^3+x^2-x+1),(x^2+1),(x+1)}. Is this right? I'm just skeptical since I can't find a way to get the polynomial "x" from that set.

b) Determine whether or not $T$ is one-to-one and/or onto. 
If I found the right kernel then this would not be one-to-one since the kernel isn't 0, but for the range, how do I know if it is onto? Since there wasn't a pivot in every row of the matrix I reduced in part (a), does that mean that it is not onto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the kernel, you are right and just have to explicitly write down the set.

For the range, a hint is to write the polynomial as
$$(a+c)x^3+(a+b+c)x^2+(d−a−c)x+(a+b+c+d)$$
$$=a(x^3+x^2-x+1)+b(x^2+1)+c(x^3+x^2-x+1)+d(x+1)$$
and try to see what the image could be.

In summary, by your calculation, we can have 
$$\text{Ker}~T=\{\begin{bmatrix}
-t & 0 \\ 
t & 0
\end{bmatrix}|t\in\mathbb{R}\}$$
which is a one-dimensional subspace.

Besides, the image of $T$ is spanned by the basis $\{x^3+x^2-x+1,x^2+1,x+1\},$ so the image is of dimension $3$ while the dimension of $P_3$ is 4, and hence $T$ is not onto.

Comment: Aren't I then simplifying the same matrix? How exactly would I find the image?

Comment: That is, what is the dimension of the space $\{a(x^3+x^2-x+1)+b(x^2+1)+c(x^3+x^2-x+1)+d(x+1)|a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}\}?$

Comment: So when I reduce that matrix, I get that the first, second, and fourth columns are linearly independent, and the third is redundant. But how do I write the range? Is the basis for the range then just the equations {(x^3+x^2-x+1),(x^2+1),(x+1)}?

Comment: The kernel's basis is just formed by the matrix you gave, and right, you just have to check if it really forms a basis of $P_3.$

Comment: I think that that set is a basis since they are linearly independent, but I am skeptical. For example, how would I get the polynomial "x"? It doesn't look like I can get that from that set.

Comment: And for determining whether T is onto, the matrix that I simplified for both the kernel and range was singular, so does this mean that it is not onto?

Comment: First, $x^2$ may not be in the image, and you can check by solving it directly! Besides, if the image of $T$ is not the whole $P_3$ (you can check by dimension, then it is not onto.

Comment: So how do I know for sure that my basis is good? And since the matrix that I simplified to get the kernel and range was singular (not a pivot in every row) does that mean that T is not onto?

Comment: I edited my answer to make all things clear.

Comment: in you answer, you have in the basis the vector (x^2), shouldn't it be (x^2+1)? by looking at what b is multiplied by

Comment: that's a typo and fixed~